# Solr return page contents _text_ in query results

Tags: solr, lucene

Is there a way to return page contents (which is indexed in `_text_` field) or the textual content of an indexed document in the returned results from a Solr query?

The document page contents are indexed in `_text_` field, but if I use that as my filtered list (fl) I just get {} returned.

Comment: Could you show your example of the query? Are you sure that your _text_ field is stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default definition for the `_text_` field is for it to be indexed but not stored, which means you can use if for searches (e.g. in the `q` parameter) but you cannot fetch its value (e.g. in the `fl` parameter)

You can look at the definition for this field with the following command:

```
$ curl localhost:8983/solr/name-of-core/schema/fields/_text_
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":2},
  "field":{
    "name":"_text_",
    "type":"text_general",
    "multiValued":true,
    "indexed":true,
    "stored":false}}
```

Comment: Thanks.. I had searched and reached the conclusion it was indexed and not stored.  Your cURL definition certainly helped me.  I assumed that if you can query the index and find a match that you should still be able to return the indexed values, even as a 'bag of words' without the stop words etc.